# PHPmyAdmin does not allow me to create stored procedures

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem when I try to create stored procedures (routines) on PHPmyAdmin. When I try to create them I get this error message:

#1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100427. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

I found this problem on my Macbook with Ventura OS installed on it. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked.